# Wrong tags while editing on mobile web

Tags: support, mobile-web

Using mobile web browser (Android, Chrome), clicking the edit button on a question results with wrong tags showing above the edit box.

I have refreshed the page several times to make sure this is not a caching issue.

[image: 1st screen]

[image: 2nd screen]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Those aren't the tags on the questions. They are the suggested tags based on the content and title of the question. The actual tags for the question are in the editable textbox directly below. Clicking on a suggestion would add it to the list of tags.

Comment: Thanks. Sure is confusing though...

Comment: @KobyDouek I agree it's confusing. It would make sense to show them under and maybe head them as _Suggested Tags_

Comment: Really confusing UI - I thought that I'm alone with that feeling. Because of it I decide not to touch tags if making edit on mobile...